# Sorting by rank and total where multiple entries may exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.2.1
```

My model is contributions, with the following fields:

```
event, contributor, date, amount
```

The table would have something like this:

```
earth_day, joe, 2014-04-14, 400
earth_day, joe, 2015-05-19, 400
lung_day, joe, 2015-05-20, 800
earth_day, john, 2015-05-19, 600
lung_day, john, 2014-04-18, 900
lung_day, john, 2015-05-21, 900
```

I have built an index view that shows all these fields and I implemented code to sort (and reverse order) by clicking on the column titles in the Index view.

What I would to do is have the Index view displayed like this:

```
Event    Contributor    Total    Rank
```

Where event is only listed once per contributor and the total is sum of all contributions for this event by the contributor and rank is how this contributor ranks relative to everyone else for this particular event.

I am toying with having a separate table where only a running tally is kept for each event/contributor and a piece of code to compute rank and re-insert it in the table, then use that table to drive views.

Can you think of a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a running tally is a fine option. Writes will slow down, but reads will be fast.

Another way is to create a database view, if you are using postgresql, something like:

```
-- Your table structure and data
create table whatever_table (event text, contributor text, amount int);
insert into whatever_table values ('e1', 'joe', 1);
insert into whatever_table values ('e2', 'joe', 1);
insert into whatever_table values ('e1', 'jim', 0);
insert into whatever_table values ('e1', 'joe', 1);
insert into whatever_table values ('e1', 'bob', 1);

-- Your view
create view event_summary as (
  select
    event,
    contributor,
    sum(amount) as total,
    rank() over (order by sum(amount) desc) as rank
  from whatever_table
  group by event, contributor
);

-- Using the view
select * from event_summary order by rank;
 event | contributor | total | rank
-------+-------------+-------+------
 e1    | joe         |     2 |    1
 e1    | bob         |     1 |    2
 e2    | joe         |     1 |    2
 e1    | jim         |     0 |    4
(4 rows)
```

Then you have an ActiveRecord class like:

```
class EventSummary < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :event_summary
end
```

and you can do stuff like `EventSummary.order(rank: :desc)` and so on. This won't slow down writes, but reads will be a little slower, depending on how much data you are working with.

Postgresql also has support for materialized views, which could give you the best of both worlds, assuming you can have a little bit of lag between when the data is entered and when the summary table is updated.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I do 99% reads and 1% writes. I will use it for another app